# PCACompute on Unity

Tags: c#, opencv, unity-game-engine

I try to learn about how pca work. I write a code but I have a problem when I use PCACompute it's no output data.Can someone help me?
Thank.

```
Mat mat = new Mat(5, 1, CvType.CV_32FC3);
mat.put(0,0,new float[]{10.0f,5.0f,0.8f});
mat.put(1,0,new float[]{20.9f,9.2f,0.9f});
mat.put(2,0,new float[]{2.7f,4.8f,0.7f});
mat.put(3,0,new float[]{13.0f,7.9f,0.9f});
mat.put(4,0,new float[]{50.9f,1.2f,1.0f});
Mat mean = new Mat();
Mat eigenvectors = new Mat();
Core.PCACompute(mat, mean, eigenvectors);
Debug.Log("eigenvectors dump = " + eigenvectors.dump ()); // Print []
mat1.Dispose ();
mean.Dispose ();
eigenvectors.Dispose ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use 3 channels?

Maybe you can try to increase the columns instead.

```
Mat mat = new Mat(5, 3, CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

or you can make an array and change it to Mat using

```
    data= np.zeros([[1,2,3] ,[1,2,3]], np.float32)
    Mat mat = cv.fromarray(data)
```